# Pinterest style grid of pictures

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, user-interface, grid

I have a database which contains the URL and description of images. I want to arrange them in a form similar to that of [Pinterest](http://pinterest.com/). Also I would like to have the functionality of 'fetching pins' (when the Scroll Bar is at the bottom then the pictures load) and adding description and saving it.

How could I achieve that? Any theoretical idea or a tutorial would be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a nice example of Jquery and the Masonry plugin at www.maxmedia.com. I've wrote a version for TYPO3 (using Masonry). It's basically a bin-packing algorithm or a treemap algorithm and it adds to the DOM  sorting in vertical columns and then horizontal rows.

Comment: How could i use this when the images are comming from the database dynamically . I want them to be loaded as a infinty Scroll list

Comment: There is jquery plugin on the masonry website for infinite scrolling. Basiscally you must use a limit in your sql clause.

Comment: I have 100 Pictures in my DB .
Using PHP if I Echo all  of them then the page will be heavy. 

How could I Integrate Masonry to Fetch images from the MYSQL DB ?
I am a bit confused regarding this...

Comment: If this your homework then tag it. Also you need to vote when you want that people help you.

Comment: Its not my HomeWork :)

I was just wondering ,How would it be possible that Masonry to Fetch images from the MYSQL DB

Comment: Hmmm, I already explained how masonry works. When you want to know how you can fetch images from a database why don't you open another questions?

Answer (score 5):

Check out the 
 [jQuery Masonry plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com/)
and
 [Isotope plugin](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)

Comment: Wow, Isotope looks great! +1 (side note: for commercial applications, there is a small license fee).

Comment: @Gaby - How could i use this when the images are comming from the database dynamically . I want them to be loaded as a infinty Scroll list